# cyclist and the headwind

Tags: vector-spaces, fluid-dynamics

I had a question where you had to determine the angle between the cyclist and the headwind. Then you had to determine the probability when there was a headwind.

Now my angle I found was $\theta=\cos^{-1}(\frac{v_{cyclist}}{v_{wind}})$. Now the queston was what is the probability if $v_{cyclist}=20km/h$ and$v_{wind}=10km/h$ and $v_{wind}=40km/h$.

my way to calculate the probability is: $1-\frac{\cos^{-1}(\frac{v_{cyclist}}{v_{wind}})}{\pi}$ but this doesn't really give a probability. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: So you have to calculate the probability of headwind? Do we know anything about the distribution of the wind speed or angle?

Comment: No. The question only gives the information that you ride a bycicle and then you can have headwind. I found out that you can only have headwind if $\theta$ is in $[0,\pi/2]] $so that's how I calculate my angle

Comment: You don't have anything given about the distribution of anything. But I thought that the probability that you have headwind = 1- the probability that you don't have headwind=1- the probability that $\phi> \pi/2$